# What does 赔着 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

赔： compensate, pay for

I can't really get '赔着笑脸' Maybe 'it cost him his smile to leave' i.e. he was sad to leave???

Or is there some other meaning in 赔？

八戒偷眼一看，那三个女儿美如天仙，不由得想入非非，赔着笑脸走了过去。

Comment: [“赔着笑脸”对呢还是“陪着笑脸”对呢](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/337268467.html)

Comment: 陪笑脸 is in dictionaries:bkrs:[put up a smiling face in order to please another] 以笑脸对人, 使人息怒或使人高兴
他在和旁人接触时, 已经不自觉地习惯于一种陪笑脸的谦卑表情
péi xiào liǎn
对人装出笑脸。
西游记．第三十回：「只见那怪怒目攒眉，咬牙切齿。那公主还陪笑脸迎道：『郎君有何事这等烦恼？』」
亦作「赔笑脸」。
meet rudeness with a flattering smile

Answer (score 2):

> [賠](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/3325/)
>
> *(1)compensate; indemnify*
>
> *(2) apologize*

[賠笑](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E8%B3%A0%E7%AC%91) = smile apologetically

[**赔着**]笑脸 = [**serve up**] a smiling face (apologetically)

*八戒 had naughty thoughts about the three girls. His subconscious guilty feeling was showing on his face with an apologetic smile*

Answer (score 1):

赔笑: literally, you "pay" your smile to sb. , implying 讨好， curry favor with sb, show your goodness and etc.

Well, 陪笑 is you just follow someone to smile and it doesn't have the connotation of being a suck-up.